# MySQL Left Outer Join or inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

```
tbl_House
House_Code (Unique, PK)
Description


tbl_Room
Room_id(pk, auto increment)
House_Code
room_name
available_date


tbl_RoomBook
book_id
House_Code
Room_id
Checkin
Checkout
```

Ok, I am trying to get all the records from those three tables.

The relationship between tables are.

One house with many rooms and one room with many reservation records

I used Query below but I do not think this works completely the way I want

because they're using the house_code to keep the uniqueness...(I think.)

```
   SELECT H.house_code, H.description
    FROM House H
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Room R
          ON H.house_code = R.house_code
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Room_Book RB
          ON H.house_code = RB.house_code
```

Comment: What is the way you want?

Comment: You're only selecting `house_code` and `description` from `House`; you're not selecting any fields from `Room` or `Room_Book`, what do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

For this type of query, `inner join` should be fine.  There is no reason to think that codes would be in one of the tables (say `room`) that are not defined in the master table.

However, your last join should probably include the room id as well:

```
SELECT H.house_code, H.description
FROM House H INNER JOIN
     Room R
     ON H.house_code = R.house_code INNER JOIN
     Room_Book RB
     ON H.house_code = RB.house_code RB.Room_Id = R.Room_Id;
```

This is a bit speculative.  Sample data would clarity the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be:

```
SELECT H.house_code, H.description
FROM House H
   INNER JOIN Room R
      ON H.house_code = R.house_code
   INNER JOIN Room_Book RB
      ON H.house_code = RB.Room_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of the left joins you're going to get House records whether any rooms are listed or any of its Rooms were booked.

There are going to be duplicate records. You'll see a listing of each house code and description repeated for as many rooms multiplied by the Room_Book record count.

If you want the records to be unique, only query the House table or do some type of group by or use Select Distinct.

Suggestion: Show some sample entries in each table and then the result set you would like to get and you'll get more help.